# In computer graphics programming, how to rotate a plane to coincident with another plane Z=0

Tags: graphics, geometry

A plane P is determined by a point p0 and a normal n. It's easy to determine that P intersects with Z=0 at line l. I need to rotate P with the axis of l, so P will coincident with Z=0. I can vectors dot product to calculate the angle between the normal n and axis z to determine the angle between P and Z=0(cosAngle = n.(0,0,1)/(|n|*1)). But this angle won't tell you that you should rotate around l in clockwise or counter clockwise. In mathmatics quizs, there is usually a drawing provided, so you know which way to rotate. But in programming, there is no such a drawing. How to determine which way to rotate correctly and efficiently?

Comment: equation Z=0 represent the XY plane

Comment: I've never seen that notation before. So you're asking how to rotate the normal vector of one plane so that it has the same direction as the vector of another plane?

Comment: I think so. Not just same direction, but two planes will coincidence. I know the degree need to rotate, but don't know clockwise or counter clockwise.

Comment: Clockwise and counter-clockwise are dependent upon your coordinate system. Just out of curiosity, why would you ever need to do this?

Comment: I don't think that's the right answer. What I want is: I have a plane P is determined by a point p0 and a normal n. On XY plane, I have tens of points represent a circle. I want to transform that circle onto P, and the circle's center will be at p0.

Comment: Oh, okay. That's a bit different.

Comment: Your problem is impossible to solve without giving a coordinate system for the second plane.